# PHP - Check if any nested array is not empty

Tags: php, arrays

If i have a nested array as follows, how can I check if any of the `dates` arrays are NOT empty?

```
$myArray =  [ 
    '1' =>  [ 'dates' => []],

    '2' =>  [ 'dates' => []],

    '3' =>  [ 'dates' => []],

    ...      
 ]
```

I know I can check this by doing a foreach loop:

```
$datesAreEmpty = true;
foreach($myArray as $item) {

  if (!empty($item['dates'])) {
      $datesAreEmpty = false;
  }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: as code is working (as suggested) - may be off-topic here and better for code review SE? :)

Comment: `count` with second parameter?

Comment: you can try array_filter()

Comment: Isn't one `foreach` loop elegant enough?

Comment: @u_mulder how do you count with second parameter?

Comment: You can use `array_reduce()` but it is like `foreach` and isn't elegant

Comment: @adam78 added answer with `count`.

Comment: `$datesAreEmpty = array_filter($myArray, function($x) { return  ! empty($x['dates']); }) ? false : true ;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in 3 steps

- check each element is_array()
- if Yes, then check size($element)
- if its greater than 0 then true otherwise false

Comment: And why would this be more 'elegant'?

Answer (score 0):

More elegant? No, I don't think so. Actually, you can break the loop after the first non-empty to make this check short-circuit, that's a tiny improvement, but this is THE way to do it.

Using array_walk (which will be mentioned in minutes I'm sure) is slower and less readable; also, there are tricky solutions with serialization (finding non-empty date strings by strpos or regex) but you don't gain anything by applying them.

Stick with this solution, and use a break on first hit. #chefstip ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using second argument for `count` will count you all items in array including subarrays. This is not a solution for all cases as in other answers, and has some initial assumptions which can be not clear, but still:

```
// Suppose you have array of your structure
$myArray =  [ 
    '1' =>  ['dates' => []],
    '2' =>  ['dates' => []],
    '3' =>  ['dates' => []],
];
// compare 
var_dump(count($myArray), count($myArray, true));
// you see `3` and `6` 
//  - 3 is count of outer elements
//  - 6 is count of all elements

// Now if there're no other keys in subarrays except `dates` 
// you can expect that `count` of all elements is __always__
// twice bigger than `count` of outer elements

// When you add some value to `dates`:
$myArray =  [ 
    '1' =>  ['dates' => ['date-1']],
    '2' =>  ['dates' => []],
    '3' =>  ['dates' => []],
];
// compare 
var_dump(count($myArray), count($myArray, true));
// you see `3` (outer elements) and `7` (all elements)
// So, you have __not empty__ `dates` when `count` of all elements 
// is more than doubled count of outer elements:

$not_empty_dates = 2 * count($myArray) < count($myArray, true);

// Of course if you have other keys in subarrays
// code should be changed accordingly, that's why
// it is not clear solution, but still it can be used
```

A working fiddle https://3v4l.org/TanG4.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done iteratively with array_filter:

```
// This will be empty if all array elements are empty.
$filtered = array_filter($myArray, '_filter_empty');

/**
 * Recursively remove empty elements from array.
 */
function _filter_empty($element) {
  if (!is_array($element)) {
    return !empty($element);
  }
  return array_filter($element, '_filter_empty');
}
```